# Show popup once?

Tags: java, android, database, string, algorithm

I am trying to show a popup, and if the user clicks dont show again, I want to never show it again. However, the `dont show again` button is not working. I am using shared preferences:

```
        if (dialogPrefs.getBoolean("Show", true) == true) {

            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle("Blah")
                    .setMessage("Blah blah blah ")
                    .setNegativeButton("Not now", null)
                    .setNeutralButton("Don't show again", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialogEditor = dialogPrefs.edit();
                            dialogEditor.putBoolean("Show", false);
                            dialogEditor.commit();
                        }
                    })
                    .setPositiveButton("Enable", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                         enable();
                        }
                    }).show();
```

My preferences and editor are declared in the beginning as such:

```
SharedPreferences dialogPrefs;
SharedPreferences.Editor dialogEditor;
```

The shared prefs are initialized in `onCreate()`.

Please let me know what the problem may be.

Thanks,

Ruchir

Comment: please show how you initialized dialogPrefs and dialogEditor in the onCreate method, or post the complete code

Answer (score 0):

`SharedPreferences.Editor.commit()` returns a boolean, indicating the status of write to the actual SharedPreferences object. See if `commit()` returned `true`. Also, make sure, you're not editing the same SharedPreference using two Editors. The last editor to commit, will have its changes reflected.

**Update** Your code works fine, when I run it. I don't see anything wrong in your code. Please make sure you're writing to and reading from the same SharedPreferences.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the declaration of the `SharedPreferences`; it is all declared but...not initialized! Where should the os write your key-value data?

I suggest you to read this [Get a Handle to a SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html#GetSharedPreferences)

Try this code, I tested it and work:

```
SharedPreferences dialogPrefs = this.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
final SharedPreferences.Editor dialogEditor = dialogPrefs.edit();


if (dialogPrefs.getBoolean("Show", true)) {

    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("Blah")
            .setMessage("Blah blah blah ")
            .setNegativeButton("Not now", null)
            .setNeutralButton("Don't show again", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialogEditor.putBoolean("Show", false);
                    dialogEditor.commit();
                }
            })
            .setPositiveButton("Enable", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Log.i("TAG", "onClick: enable");
                }
            }).show();
}
}
```

Comment: It is initialized, look at the bottom of my answer, where I state it is declared at the beginning.

Comment: ruchir yes it is declared but not initialized

Comment: Oh, I am sorry I forgot to show the initialization. It is actually initialized in the onCreate(). I will edit my question :)

Comment: ok! post the complete code, thus we can run your snippet to help you!

Comment: But even trying the way written in your answer doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this:

```
if (!dialogPrefs.getBoolean("Show", false)) {//don't show again will work
```

instead of:

```
if (dialogPrefs.getBoolean("Show", true) == true) {//this will always show dialog
```